# What is this in javascript: "var var1 = var1 || []"

Tags: javascript

I just want to increase my core javascript knowledge.

Sometimes I see this statement but I don't know what it does:

```
var var1 = var1 || [];
```

What does it means and/or what's it for, and how do you use it?

Thank you.

Comment: Thats an interesting way to accomplish the goal. But why would it randomly turn null in the first place?

Comment: @TheLQ: It could be an optional parameter.

Comment: @SLaks: but then it wouldn't need `var`, right?

Comment: @cambraca Useless code that generates warnings creates nice "wtfs" for future developers :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logical operators in JavaScript actually evaluate to one of the two objects. When you use `a || b` it evaluates to `b` if `a` is false, or to `a` if `a` is true. Thus `a || []` will be `a` if `a` is any value that is true, or `[]` if `a` is any value that is false.

It's much more obvious to use `if (!a) { a = [] };`

Comment: Not false, but rather "falsy". The difference is subtle but important. Falsy values in JavaScript can be 0, null, false, an empty string, undefined, or NaN. `null || 5` returns `5`, even though `null != false`.

Answer (score 11):

Basically, it looks to see if a variable `var1` already exists and is "truthy". If it is, it assigns the local `var1` variable its value; if not, it gets assigned an empty array.

This works because the JavaScript `||` operator returns the value of the first truthy operand, or the last one, if none are truthy. `var1 || var2` returns `var1` if it's truthy, or `var2` otherwise.

Here are some examples:

```
var somevar;
somevar = 5 || 2; // 5
somevar = 0 || 2; // 2
somevar = 0 || null; // null
```

Values that aren't "truthy": `false`, `0`, `undefined`, `null`, `""` (empty string), and `NaN`. Empty arrays and objects are considered truthy in JavaScript, unlike in some other languages.

Answer (score 7):

It assigns an empty array to `var1`, if the boolean representation of it is false (for example it hasn't been initialized).

Comment: False values in JS: http://www.joeyjavas.com/2007/08/04/javascript-true-false-checking-for-boolean-values/. I would say if if the "value is not truthy", but...

Answer (score 5):

Basically if `var1` is `NULL` or `false`, `var1` will be set to an empty `array`.

Comment: Incomplete list of false values. See http://www.joeyjavas.com/2007/08/04/javascript-true-false-checking-for-boolean-values/ (also, null is the keyword, NULL is just an identifier)

Comment: I would prefer to see a distinction between the object type itself (which could be anything) and the expression type (which is Boolean). The value of var1 gets converted to a Boolean (to be evaluated for truthiness) in the expression (var1 || []).

Answer (score 3):

Javascript or (||) works a bit differently to some other languages, it returns the first "truthy" value instead of a boolean. This is being used in this case to say "Set the value of var1 to `var1`, but if that value is "falsey" set it to `[]`".

This is often used to set a "default" value to a variable that may or may not be set already, such as an argument to a function.

Answer (score 1):

The `||` operator evaluates the first of its operands that is "truthy".

`[]` is an empty array.  (`[ "Hi!" ]` is an array of one string)

Therefore, the expression `x || []` evaluates to `x` if it's "truthy" or an empty array if it isn't.

This allows the `var1` parameter to be optional.

Answer (score 1):

The statement assigns an empty array to var1.

---

**longer answer and explanation:**

This happens because var1 is not initialized at that time. Non-initialized is a falsy value.

take this statement:

```
var1 = var1 || [];
```

If var1 is not initialized it becomes an empty array, it if is an empty array nothing happens as its assigned to an empty array, if var1 is `false`, `null`, or [any other value that javascript things of as false](http://www.joeyjavas.com/2007/08/04/javascript-true-false-checking-for-boolean-values/), it becomes an empty array, if var1 is anything other value, nothing happens as it is assigned to itself. (thanks pst for the link).

In short, its a stupid statement that's neither readable nor useful, but you're smart for wanting to know what it means. :)

Answer (score 1):

While this has been pointed out as 'being a silly statement', I present the following two counters:

(Just to keep people on their toes and reinforce some of the "finer details" of JavaScript.)

1)

`var` is the variable is already `local`. E.g.

```
function x (y) {
  var y = y || 42 // redeclaration warning in FF, however it's "valid"
  return y
}
x(true) // true
x()     // 42
```

2)

`var` is function-wide annotation (it is "hoisted" to the top) and not a declaration at the point of use.

```
function x () {
  y = true
  var y = y || 42
}
x()      // true
```

I do not like code like either of the preceding, but...

Because of the hoisting, and allowed re-declarations, the code in the post has these semantics:

```
var var1
if (!var1) {
  var1 = []
}
```

**Edit** I am not aware of how "strict mode" in Ed.5 influences the above.