# What does this Javascript line do?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “var _gaq = _gaq || []; ” for ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538252/what-is-var-gaq-gaq-for)

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

I'm not sure what this line is doing? Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Also a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281795/what-is-this-in-javascript-var-var1-var1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to doing

```
var _gaq = _gaq ? : _gaq : [];
```

It means that if `_gaq` is set, it'll set it to `_gaq`, otherwise it will default to a new empty array.

- `var` means it's local scope
- `_gaq` is the name of the variable
- `||` means or

It's saying that if `_gaq` doesn't already exist, set it to a new array which is what `[]` means.

Comment: @thephpdeveloper You beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

It declares a variable named `_gaq`. If that variable was already defined, and is a **truthy** value, then the line is equivalent to writing

```
var _gaq = _gaq;
```

If `_gaq` is a **falsy** value, then the newly declare variable is an empty array.

Some reference on truthiness and falsiness in JavaScript:

- http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript
- http://javascript.crockford.com/style2.html

Answer (score 0):

It checks if _gaq is defined if not assigns an array object to _gaq.

its equivalent to

```
if(!_gaq){
 var _gaq = [];
}
```

Comment: That's not similar at all, that's declaring a global variable